# Class moderncv, style{banking} \maketitle issues

Tags: texmaker, moderncv

I keep getting an error while trying to use class `moderncv` with `\moderncvstyle{banking}`. This is the error that I get:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\makehead ...sfont \color {color2}\@moreextrainfo
\par }\medskip
l.77 \makecvtitle
```

The same happens with the `\makelettertitle`. Any suggestions on what's going on or how to fix this?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}      
\moderncvstyle{banking}                             
\moderncvcolor{blue}                             
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[scale=0.775,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
```

> THIS IS WHAT IS CAUSING THE PROBLEM, but I don't know how to fix it

```
\newcommand\moreextrainfo[1]{\def\@moreextrainfo{#1}}
\patchcmd\makehead{\\[2.5em]}

{\par{\centering\addressfont\color{color2}\@moreextrainfo\par}\medskip}% {}{}



% personal data
\name{J.}{Doe}
\title{}                               
\phone[home]{{\faHome} somewhere} 
\phone[mobile]{+1~(000)~000~0000}                   
\email{somewhere@gmail.com}                              
\quote{N/A}                                

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle
\vspace{-2.5em}
```

Comment: That is not an mwe. We need a full but minimal example, that we can copy and test as is. Here we have to guess half the contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, your given code is not complete or compilable :-((

Your given error `Undefined control sequence.` should not occur with your given code snippet.

Please see the following MWE (important code additions are marked with `<=====`) I created with some wild guessing:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle{banking}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[scale=0.775,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}

\makeatletter % <=======================================================
\newcommand\moreextrainfo[1]{\def\@moreextrainfo{#1}}
\patchcmd\makehead
  {\\[2.5em]}%
  {\par{\centering\addressfont\color{color2}\@moreextrainfo\par}\medskip}%
  {}{}
\makeatother % <========================================================

\name{J.}{Doe}
\title{empty title}
\address{Address}{1111}{FRANCE}
\phone[home]{{\faHome} somewhere}
\phone[mobile]{+1~(000)~000~0000}
\email{somewhere@gmail.com}
\moreextrainfo{more extra info more extra info} % <=====================

\quote{N/A}


\begin{document}
\makecvtitle
\end{document}
```

With an defined content for command `\moreextrainfo` and masking the usage of `@` with commands `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` you get then the following resulting page:

[image: resulting page]

Please see that with this code you **have** to define an `\moreextrainfo`!

Next time please add an complete code (short MWE, minimal working example) to your question we can copy and play with ...

If my guess does not reflect your situation change your question please by adding an complete short code resulting in your issue.  Add the version of `moderncv` you are using (I'm using the current one: 2.0.0) ...